# Certain folders are always missing using Rsync to server

Tags: linux, ssh, freebsd, rsync, freenas

I have tried several different ways using `rsync` modules and `ssh` trying to pull my linux desktop from my freenas server and no matter how I do it, certain folders are always missing.

I am trying to pull the whole system but certain folders either don't show up, or are empty. My users folders always show up but it seems to be only certain root folders that do not

I've tried `--archive`, and not but I'd like to use:

```
--archive --delete --xattrs  --hard-links \
 --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/media/*","/mnt/*","/lost+found"}
```

When I don't run it in archive mode I only get these folders:

```
drwxr-x---  6 root  wheel  10 Nov 21 00:44 ./
drwxr-x---  3 john  john  6 Nov 21 00:43 ../
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  7 Nov 21 00:44 bin@ -> usr/bin
drwxr-xr-x  4 root  wheel  7 Nov 21 00:44 boot/
drwxr-xr-x  20 root  wheel  30 Nov 21 00:44 dev/
drwxr-xr-x  87 root  wheel  181 Nov 21 00:44 etc/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  3 Nov 21 00:44 home/
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  7 Nov 21 00:44 lib@ -> usr/lib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  7 Nov 21 00:44 lib64@ -> usr/lib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  7 Nov 21 00:44 sbin@ -> usr/bin
```

In archive mode, all folders are present, but the ones that aren't listed above are empty.

Does anyone know how to make `rsync` work properly to do this?

Comment: What user are you rsyncing from, do they have permission to access these folders?

Comment: Yes, I have full permissions, I'm using root.